# Distribution of discrete random variable $X$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I am stuck on a question regarding discrete random variable. The question is as follows:

The probability mass function of $X$ with $x \in \mathbb{N}:=\{0,1,2, \ldots\}$ satisfies the following:

\begin{align}
\frac{(=)}{(=+1)}=x+1
\end{align}

I am asked to find $(=0)$ and identify the distribution of $X$

I worked out that $(=0)=(=1)$ from the given PMF but not sure what to do next and how to identify the type of distribution of $X$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Say that $P(X=0) = a$ and proceed from there. [Hint: you'll find $P(x) = a/x!$ and can determine $a$ afterward].

Comment: @nicola yes I have already found out that *P(x)=P(X=0)/x!*  but not sure how to determine the real value of *P(X=0)*

Comment: To determine $a$ just set $\sum_0^\infty P(x) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Express this as a recurrence:
$$
\pi_1 = \pi_0\\
\pi_2 = \frac{\pi_1}{2}=\frac{\pi_0}{1 \cdot 2}\\
\pi_3 = \frac{\pi_0}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3}\\
$$
Hence
$$
\pi_k = \frac{\pi_0}{k!}
$$
Since probabilities sum to $1$, you get $1$ on LHS, and $\exp(1) \pi_0$ on RHS and the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a poisson distribution $X\sim Po(1)$

then you have that

$$\frac{\mathbb{P}[X=x]}{\mathbb{P}[X=x+1]}=\frac{\frac{e^{-1}}{x!}}{\frac{e^{-1}}{(x+1)!}}=x+1$$

thus

$$\mathbb{P}[X=0]=e^{-1}$$